# Как сделать чтобы работал searchBar в двух TableViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, search, mobile-development

```html
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating  {
    
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var FirstTableArray = ["1-секция","2-секция","3-секция","4-секция","5-секция","6-секция"]
    var SecondArray = [SecondTable]()
    var ThirdArray = [ThirdView]()
    var filtredData = [String]()
    var inSearchMode = false
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        
      
        SecondArray = [SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["FirstClass","SecondFirst","ThirdFirst"]),SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["SecondClass","SecondSecond","ThirdSecond"]),SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["ThirdClass","SecondThird","ThirdThird"]),SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["FourthClass","SecondThird","ThirdThird"]),SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["FifthClass","SecondSecond","ThirdSecond"]),SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["Sixthclass","SecondSecond","ThirdSecond"])]
        
        ThirdArray = [ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["dssd","vsf","gdffv"]),
                      ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["dssd","vsf","gdffv"]),
                      ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["dssd","vsf","gdffv"]),
                      ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["dssd","vsf","gdffv"]),
                      ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["dssd","vsf","gdffv"]),
                      ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["dssd","vsf","gdffv"])]
        
        filtredData = FirstTableArray
        
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        
        //     self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    
        
    }
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
            filtredData = FirstTableArray
        } else {
            filtredData = FirstTableArray.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())}
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    //  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    //     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    //}
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return self.filtredData.count
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! UITableViewCell
        
        Cell.textLabel?.text = self.filtredData[indexPath.row]
        Cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.filtredData[indexPath.row]
        
        return Cell
    }
    
    
    /*
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     print("Row+++++ \(indexPath.row) selected")
     let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
     if let cellselected: String = currentCell.textLabel!.text {
     print("cell selected:\(cellselected)")
     }
     }
     */
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      
        var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as! NSIndexPath
        
        var DestViewController = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController
        
        var SecondTableArrayTwo: SecondTable
        
        SecondTableArrayTwo = SecondArray[indexPath.row]
        
        DestViewController.SecondArray = SecondTableArrayTwo.SecondTitle
        
        var ThirdAnswerArray: ThirdView
        
        ThirdAnswerArray = ThirdArray[indexPath.row]
        
        DestViewController.SecondAnswerArray = ThirdAnswerArray.ThirdViewArray
        
     //   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      //  let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? FirstTableViewController
        
      //  vc?.FirstTableArray
        
       // self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        
     
    }
        
    }
    
    //swift 4 xcode 9
```

Здравствуйте я хочу добавить к себе в приложение SearchBar у меня все получилось и работает но он работает только для одного TableviewController когда я пользуюсь им он выдает результаты только из Первого TableViewController но у меня есть второй TableViewController который является ячейками первого контроллера.Вопрос в том как сделать что поиск искал результаты второго TableViewController.Если есть какой видеоурок неважно на каком языке.Или что то ещё скиньте.Жду ваших ответов!

Comment: Поток сознания? Можете привести пример кода?

Comment: Так а где здесь второй SearchControler?